# Magento Shipping Methods for Saturday Delivery

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, fedex

In Magento 1.9 Admin config section under Fedex, 2 shipping methods we use in our store are not offered.

- FedEx 2 Day Saturday Delivery
- Priority Overnight Saturday Delivery

I have added them to the code in Mage/Usa and they show up but are not functioning.

I am using these service codes:

```
'FEDEX2DAYSATURDAYDELIVERY'     => 'FEDEX_2_DAY_SATURDAY_DELIVERY',
'PRIORITYOVERNIGHTSATURDAYDELIVERY' => 'PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT_SATURDAY_DELIVERY',
```

And have added these 2 options to the wsdl files.
I know I need to create my own modules for this, but trying to get this to work before complicating the process.

Comment: I found this similar situation someone was having with UPS and there wasn't an answer to this one either. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628104/saturday-delivery-option-ups-extension-magento

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?